# Slicing in PyTables

Tags: performance, optimization, pytables

What is the fastest way to slice arrays that are saved in h5 using PyTables?

The scenario is the following:

1. The data was already saved (no need to optimize here):

   ```
   filters = tables.Filters(complib='blosc', complevel=5)
   h5file = tables.open_file(hd5_filename, mode='w',
                             title='My Data',
                             filters=filters)
   group = h5file.create_group(h5file.root, 'Data', 'Data')

   X_atom = tables.Float32Atom(shape=[50,50,50])
   X = h5file.create_carray(group, 'X', atom=X_atom, title='XData',
                        shape=(1000,), filters=filters)
   ```
2. The data is opened :

   ```
   h5file = tables.openFile(hd5_filename, mode="r")
   node = h5file.getNode('/', data_node)
   X = getattr(node, X_str)
   ```
3. This is where I need optimization, I need to make a lot of the following kind of array slicing that cannot be sorted, for many many indexes and different min/max locations:

   ```
   for index, min_x, min_y, min_z, max_x, max_y, max_z in my_very_long_list:    
       current_item = X[index][min_x:max_x,min_y:max_y,min_z:max_z]
       do_something(current_item)
   ```

The question is:
Is this the fastest way to do the task?